# Using variable inside of for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

The idea is I want to check if a substring is inside of a string with Batch script.

For example I want to check if `pass` is inside of `%rev%`. If no for loop is related, I can do:

```
if /I "%rev:pass=%" neq "%rev%" (
echo String has pass
) else (
echo it doesnt has pass
)
```

But I don't know how to use this `"%rev:pass=%"` in side of a for loop when `"%rev%"` is replaced by `%%g`

My code is here:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN (test.txt) do (
if /I "%%g:pass=" neq "%%g" (
echo String has pass
) else (
echo it doesnt has pass
)
)
```

I need to check each string inside of this test.txt if it has substring `pass`. Any help is appreciated.

I try to change the form of `%%g` but still cannot make it happen. The main idea is to check each string in the file, if the string has `pass` as a sub-string

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: This is Win Batch

Comment: I always program Batch at a loss. If I want to do something more powerful than the _simplest_ of actions, I _always_ switch to a better script engine. Windows comes preinstalled with vbscript and javascript engines. I personally keep a copy of tclsh around. And you can put the code for any of them in a .bat file if you know the magic incantation at the top (easy to Google).

Comment: `Find` can show you each line containing the case insensitive string `pass`, i.e. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "pass" 0<”test.txt"```. Conversely ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I /V "pass" 0<”test.txt"``` will show you each line which doesn't contain the case insensitive string `pass`. You could also do it with `FindStr`: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I "pass" ”test.txt"```, and ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V "pass" ”test.txt"``` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate `for` loop variables directly, so you'll need to store them in regular variables first. However, since you can't ordinarily set and use variables inside of sets, you'll need to enable delayed expansion. This can be done by adding `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top of your script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN (test.txt) do (
    set "line=%%g"
    if /I "!line:pass=!" neq "%%g" (
        echo String has pass
    ) else (
        echo it doesnt has pass
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Will match if the case is UPPER or lower.
It works by string replacement and comparison of before and after.
Also gives a running hit count. Nifty.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims= tokens=*" %%g IN (test.txt) do (
set "str1=%%g"
set "str2=!str1:pass=replace!"
if not !str1!==!str2! set /a i+=1 & echo YES - FOUND !i!)
```

Oh also. the other answer is wrong. The way it's written the two values will NEVER be equal.  Try it.

Comment: Despite `the two values will NEVER be equal` in SomethingDark's answer, it works (`Try it`). Either your statement is false, or there is some obscure magic at work...